# How to handle button click from iOS and Android par separately from Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android app using Xamarin Forms using PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in C# and Xamarin I am creating a Xamarin Forms App and want o create an button that can handle different task from different platform (i.e. iOS & Android).
Suppose I want to use a binding binding library (android binding Library and other is iOS Binding library). On a button click in Xamarin Forms App I want to execute platform specific library method for example suppose in Android Binding library there is a method `void ShowAndroidContent();` and on the other iOS Binding library there is a method `-(void)ShowiOSContent;` so On the button click if device is Android `ShowAndroidContent();` should be execute and if iOS then `ShowiOSContent();` should be execute.
My Solution Name is **XamarinFormsAppDemo**

---

**TestXamarinFormAppPage.xaml Code is:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXamarinFormApp" x:Class="TestXamarinFormApp.TestXamarinFormAppPage">
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.1"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Button Text="Click Me !" Clicked="OnButtonClicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

### **TestXamarinFormAppPage.xaml.cs Code is:-**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace TestXamarinFormApp
{
    public partial class TestXamarinFormAppPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TestXamarinFormAppPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
        int count = 0;
        public void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {




// here if device is Android the button click should be handle from MainActivity.cs in TestXamarinFormApp.Droid part and


// if device is an iOS then this button click should be handle from Main.cs in  TestXamarinFormApp.iOS




        }
    }
}
```

I'am using Xamarin Studio for it.
Can anybody help me to do this. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution of above problem It can be handle using `DependencyService` to achieve this goal I've created a .cs class for Interface object and using D`ependencyService` we can handle click from platform specific class. the followings are the code to do it.

### **Interface_Object_Class.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace TestXamarinFormApp
{
    public interface IR_Btn_Click {
        void BtnPressed ();
    }
}
```

**TestXamarinFormAppPage.xaml Code is:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXamarinFormApp" x:Class="TestXamarinFormApp.TestXamarinFormAppPage">
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.1"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Button Text="Click Me !" Clicked="OnButtonClicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**TestXamarinFormAppPage.xaml.cs Code is:-**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace TestXamarinFormApp
{
    public partial class TestXamarinFormAppPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TestXamarinFormAppPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
        public void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IR_Btn_Click> ().BtnPressed ();
        }
    }
```

and now button click can be handle by registering **assembly** from **MainPage.cs** of iOS Part of app i.e. **TestXamarinFormApp.iOS >>> MainPage.cs** as follows:-

```
using System;
using AVFoundation;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using TestXamarinFormApp.iOS;
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (MainPage))]
namespace TestXamarinFormApp.iOS
{
    public class MainPage : IR_Btn_Click
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
        }
        public void BtnPressed ()
        {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hurray ! the button is clicked from an iOS Device.");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Device.OnPlatform()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/)

```
public void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
{

    Device.OnPlatform (iOS: () => { // do iOS stuff; },
                       Android: () => { // do Android stuff; });
}
```

Comment: I can not do that because we are using different binding libraries for android and iOS and iOS binding library is not accessible in PCL so I can handle it from iOS part so I need to call a method defined in iOS part of my App can please suggest me how to achieve this goal

Comment: use DI to inject the relevant code for each platform

Comment: Yes I got it and my issue has been resolved thank you all.

Comment: `Device.OnPlatform(...)` is obsolete. Now `Device.TargetPlatform` should be used

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Device.OS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/#Device.OS). `Device.OS` will be set to one of the values of the [TargetPlatform](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TargetPlatform/) enumeration:

- iOS
- Android
- WinPhone (returned for Windows 8 Silverlight)
- Windows

This enables platform-specific checks to alter layout or functionality, such as these if statements:

```
public void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) 
  {
     //iOS
  } 
  else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android) 
  {
     //Android
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not do that because we are using different binding libraries for android and iOS and iOS binding library is not accessible in PCL so I can handle it from iOS part so I need to call a method defined in iOS part of my App can please suggest me how to achieve this goal

Comment: `Device.OS` is obsolete. Now `Device.TargetPlatform` should be used